Syntax highlighted post mortem ipdb traceback
python -m ipdb my_script_with_errors.py
(followed by an initial c to continue)
gives me ipdb post mortem debugging, in a syntax highlighted prompt. However, the initial traceback of the error is not highlighted or in the ipython style. It's the regular uncolored python style.
ipython -m ipdb my_script_with_errors.py
has the same problem.
ipython my_script_with_errors.py
gives me an ipython style syntax highlighted traceback, but then no debugging since not asking for it. This makes me think there might be a way to get the best of both worlds.
Can I get an ipython style initial traceback when using post mortem ipdb? If so, how?

I intentionally phrased this such that "No, unless changes to ipdb are made." is a valid answer if that is the case. Bonus points for explaining why ipdb currently cannot do this ofc.
